# 'grep -R string *.txt' even when top dir doesn't have a .txt file

Tags: grep

I don't recall when the recursive search '**-R**' command line switch was introduced in **grep**, but now I can't imagine life without it.

Its only problem is that if any directory in the recursion doesn't have a match for the filename wildcard, grep -R will stop and will fail to report the directories and files that do produce positive search results.

For example:

```
  grep -R skeleton_app *.xml
```

Will report only

```
AndroidManifest.xml:    <application android:label="@string/skeleton_app">
```

While:

```
  grep -R skeleton_app *
```

Will report all:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:    <application android:label="@string/skeleton_app">
Binary file bin/classes.dex matches
Binary file bin/com/example/android/skeletonapp/R$string.class matches
gen/com/example/android/skeletonapp/R.java:        public static final int skeleton_app=0x7f050000;
res/values/strings.xml:    <string name="skeleton_app">Understanding Intents</string>
```

My question: Is there a way to tell '**grep -R**' *not* to stop on filename mismatch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -R --include '*.xml' skeleton_app .
```

Comment: Thanks – and to search for a phrase, just add quotes, for example: `grep -r -include "index.html" "using Grunt to generate" .`

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` in addition to grep.

```
$ find ./ -name "*.txp" -exec grep "string" '{}' \; -print
```

Comment: Thanks but your method loses the filenames preceding the line numbers (when -n is used). Besides, this not really telling grep but rather *passing to* grep. Thus, @yan's answer is the accepted. :)