# Recursively search files named string.xml for certain text

Tags: unix, grep

This command will search all directories and subdirectories for files containing "text"

```
grep -r "text" *
```

How do i specify to search only in files that are named 'strings.xml'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll want to use `find` for this, since `grep` won't work that way recursively (as far as I know). Something like this should work:

```
find . -name "strings.xml" -exec grep "text" "{}" \;
```

The `find` command searches starting in the current directory (`.`) for a file with the name strings.xml (`-name "strings.xml"`), and then for each found file, execute the `grep` command specified. The curly braces (`"{}"`) are a placeholder that `find` uses to specify the name of the file it found. More detail can be found in `man find`.

Also note that the `-r` option to grep is no longer necessary, since `find` works recursively.

Comment: Thanks, what do the curly braces do?

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 Updated with that info.

Comment: I have used this command to find a string in particular type of files. 
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep -rn "string" "{}" \;
It shows the occurrences but file name is absent. How to output file name as well.
Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the grep command:

```
grep -r "text" /path/to/dir/strings.xml
```

Comment: Or if you don't know the directory name exactly but know the file is immediately in one of the subdirectories of the current directory, `grep "text" ./*/strings.xml` -- this will look in `./a/strings.xml`, `./b/strings.xml`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

grep supports an --include option whose use is to recurse in directories only searching file matching PATTERN. So, try something like below:

```
grep -R --include 'strings.xml' text .
```

I also tried using find which seems to be quite faster than grep:

```
find ./ -name "strings.xml" -exec grep "text" '{}' \; -print
```

These links speak about the same issue, might help you:

['grep -R string *.txt' even when top dir doesn't have a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094828/grep-r-string-txt-even-when-top-dir-doesnt-have-a-txt-file)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/run-grep-only-on-certain-files-using-wildcard-919822/

Answer (score -1):

Try below command

```
find . -type f | xargs grep "strings\.xml"
```

This will run `grep "strings\.xml"` on every file returned by `find`

Comment: The OP wants to grep *files named*  `strings.xml` for some other string. You mean `find . -type f -name strngs.xml | xargs grep "text"` ... which of course is more robustly written `find . -type f -name strings.xml -exec grep "text" {} +` as in several of the existing answers.